# finding resources in a given radius in Map, Grails Application

Tags: javascript, google-maps, grails, google-maps-api-3

I have a grails application where I want to take the address as the input and generate all the  resources around a 5 mile radius.By resources I mean things of public interest like Gym, superMarket,Clinics or any restaurants.

Can anyone please tell me how to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try google places API at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/ .I used google maps API in my Grails project. We used plain google map api javascripts (did not find any good Grails plugin). I am not sure if there is a Grails plugin for google maps api..

Comment: thanks Saurabh. I have been going through it. but I am not able to logically understand how would such a thing be possible. Can you explain a workflow of such a problem.Thanks. That would be great.

Comment: google map api or gogole places api (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places) returns response in json format. We used Groovy JSON parser to parse json objects and Grails controller to render data on UI. for ex :http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=true_or_false returns geo-coding results (lang/lat) of given address.